# How to use openconnect to connect to vpn with 2 factor authentication with Google Authenticator

Tags: vpn, openconnect

I would like to connect to vpn using openconnect.
Our company uses Google Authenticator codes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to create 2 factor codes on your pc https://github.com/arcanericky/ga-cmd
Store your account password in `~/.cisco/pass.txt`

Then use this to connect to vpn

```
echo -e "$(sudo cat ~/.cisco/pass.txt)\n$(./ga-cmd <your-ga-site-name>)" | sudo openconnect --user=<username> --passwd-on-stdin <your-vpn.com>
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can make it [working with oathtool](https://superuser.com/questions/462478/is-there-a-google-authenticator-desktop-client/826339#826339) (works fine for macOS users):

```
alias vpn="echo -e '${YOUR_PWD}\n$(cat ~/.totp_google | xargs oathtool --totp -b)' | \
  sudo openconnect {YOUR_VPN_HOST} --user=${YOUR_USERNAME} --passwd-on-stdin"
```

Your secret shoud be in `~/.totp_google` file.